# Upload EK certificate into TPM NVRAM

Tags: nvram

I am trying to use an application that utilizes the TPM EK certificate on the hardware to perform hardware attestation. I am using an UPxtreme i7 board and I noticed there was no EK certificate in the TPM NVRAM. I have been trying unsuccessfully to manually create an EK certificate and upload into the NVRAM. Any ideas on how to go about this?

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on the board and I have installed all the necessary tpm tools.

Steps I took:

1. tpm2_createek -G rsa -u ek.pub -c key.ctx // to create the ek key
2. tpm2_getekcertificate -X -o ECcert.bin -u ek.pub https://ekop.intel.com/ekcertservice/ // to get the ek certificate
3. tpm2_nvdefine 0x01c00002 -C o -s 1033 -a ppwrite|writedefine|write_stclear|ppread|ownerread|authread|no_da|written|platformcreate // to define the NVRAM index. This is where I keep getting errors.

Error:

WARNING:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_NV_DefineSpace.c:344:Esys_NV_DefineSpace_Finish() Received TPM Error
ERROR:esys:src/tss2-esys/api/Esys_NV_DefineSpace.c:122:Esys_NV_DefineSpace() Esys Finish ErrorCode (0x000002c2)
ERROR: Failed to define NV area at index 0x1C00002
ERROR: Esys_NV_DefineSpace(0x2C2) - tpm:parameter(2):inconsistent attributes
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_nvdefine

Any ideas on how to successfully define the NVRAM index and upload the certificate. Or if anyone has a better approach to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `written` flag should not be provided, it will be set when an `nvwrite` is executed, it will cause an `inconsistent attributes` error when directly set. See [Trusted Platform Module Library
Part 2: Structures - table 204](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TPM-Rev-2.0-Part-2-Structures-01.38.pdf#page=159) for more details about the flags.

The following works for me:

```bash
$ tpm2_nvdefine 0x01c00002 -C p -a 'ppwrite|writedefine|ppread|ownerread|authread|no_da|platformcreate'
$ tpm2_nvwrite 0x01c00002 -C p -i ek.cert
```

Be aware that the `0x01c00002` index is the NV index for a `RSA 2048 EK Certificate`. Use `0x01c0000a` if you want an `ECC NIST P256 EK Certificate`. See [TCG EK Credential Profile - chapter 2.2.1.4](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG_IWG_Credential_Profile_EK_V2.1_R13.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A67%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C273%2C0%5D).

To finish it up, you should lock the index so the certificate cannot be overriden:

```bash
$ tpm2_nvwritelock 0x01c00002 -C p
```

---

I hope the answer is complete enough for you :)